# How to add a value to an embeded list in lua

Tags: list, lua

I have three lists within a list, and I was wondering how to add a value to the last embedded list.
Here is an example of the list that I have:

```
l = 
{{1, 2, 3},
{4, 5, 6},
{7, 8}}
```

If I wanted to add the value 9 to the last embedded list, I would do

```
l[#l][#l[#l] + 1] = 9
```

which would change l to

```
{{1, 2, 3},
{4, 5, 6},
{7, 8, 9}}
```

Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

But you can make it easier to read by using a temporary variable:

```
local last = l[ #l ]
last[ #last+1 ] = 9
```

There is also a [`table.insert`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-table.insert) function which appends to the end of a sequence by default:

```
table.insert( l[ #l ], 9 )
```